# Difference between HttpApplication.Context and Controller.HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, httpcontext, httpapplication

In MSDN it says

[`HttpApplication.Context`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.aspx):

> Gets HTTP-specific information about the current request.

`Controller.HttpContext`:

> Gets HTTP-specific information about an individual HTTP request.

Whats the difference between them. Are they both the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are they both the same?

They are both the same. What is more, `Controller.HttpContext` is mockable (helpful for unittesting). They are point to the same data, but `Controller.HttpContext` provide more features like RouteData etc.